# Wordpress Admin Network link is missing a slash

Tags: wordpress

I cannot access to wordpress admin network page, it return error 404 page not found. And I notice the link change automatically when i open link blablabla.com/wordpress/wp-admin/network, then it auto redirect to the link blablabla.com/wordpresswp-admin/network (notice missing the slash). All other links are ok, i can access to blablabla.com/wordpress/wp-admin page without any problem. Only cannot access to network page.
how to fix it? I use a plugin name Duplicator to migrate my site from wamp localhost to shared hosting, Duplicator got warning it will have small problem to migrate multisite feature of wordpress. I guess it is the problem source. Any idea? Or shared hosting cannot read htaccess file?

htaccess file have add slash but still not works.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

I change multisite from true to false at wp_config, then the link works perfectly. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figure it out. Just open wp-config.php add a slash the line :

```
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress');
```

become

```
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
```

Comment: Saved me time in 2024 - if the multisite is at the root directory of the site, just add a / like this define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );